# How to get AD session details through ASP.NET web application?

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I am trying to get details of a AD user that logged in a directory pc. I mean that when a user logged in a pc (in AD) by his account and then open a site that's working on intranet, i'll automatically detect his account name, sAMAccountName etc.
Is that possible or i've gotta use an agent or something installed before?
I'm confused about it. I don't want to make a log-in screen for it if possible ofc.
Thanks in advice!

Comment: What you're looking for is called "Windows Authentication"

Comment: Are you just looking for something like `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`? This will return the Windows login name of the current user. Or perhaps `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` depending on your use case.